# bootstrap-datepicker set initial date not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to use the jQuery datepicker below in an MVC applicaiton. 
http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html

The basics are working, it shows the input field with the glyphicon, and when I click in the textbox the datepicker shows up. I can even select a date and it will display in the textbox.

What I'm not trying to get is to set options like the default date and autoclose. That part is not working for me and I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using jquery-1.10.2.min.js which came in the initial setup of my MVC application in Visual Studio.

I'm using he bundling to get it in the project. I've moved the rendering of the scripts from the footer to the header and then put the script to work with the datepicker directly in the View.

Anyone have a suggestion as to what I can try to get it to work? I'm starting out trying to get the StartDate to work first then I'll move on to the EndDate.

**Bundle.config**

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Reporting</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Reports", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("API", "Index", "Help", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            @if (System.DateTime.Today.Year > 2016)
            {
                <p>&copy; 2016 - @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
            }
            else
            {
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
            } 
        </footer>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**TotalHours.cshtml**

```
@model Reports.ViewModels.TotalHoursReportVM

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#StartDate').datepicker({
            title: "Start Date",
            autoClose: true,
            setDate: new Date()
        });
    });
</script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TotalHours";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Total Hours Report</h2>


<div class="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("TotalHoursRun", "Report", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary("Report creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")

        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row voffset3">
                    <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
                        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                            <input type="text" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" class="form-control">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                            <input type="text" id="EndDate" name="EndDate" class="form-control">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row voffset7">
                    <div class="cols-sm-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Run Report</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>        
    }
</div>
```

**-----  UPDATE  -----**

I found the following example that seems to work only for setting the dates. The sample I found said to call the "update" after making some settings. So far it seems to work for the dates but the "autoclose" and "title" aren't working. Those aren't as important but I'm wondering if there is a better way to work with this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var startDate = new Date();
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 7);
        var endDate = new Date();

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var startDate = new Date();
            startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 7);
            $("#StartDate").datepicker("setDate", startDate);
            $("#StartDate").datepicker("autoclose", true);
            $("#StartDate").datepicker("title", "Start Date");
            $("#StartDate").datepicker('update');


            $("#EndDate").datepicker("setDate", endDate);
            $("#EndDate").datepicker("autoclose", true);
            $("#EndDate").datepicker("title", "End Date");
            $("#EndDate").datepicker('update');
        });
    });
```

Comment: How are you setting the startDate option?  I don't see it in your code.  Are you getting any errors in the console and/or what do you see when you open up the developer toolbar for your browser?  The autoclose option appears in their documentation as all lowercase.  You are setting autoClose.  Perhaps that is stopping the automatic close from working.

Comment: I a little progress but I'm not sure it's the correct way. Still not everything is working but at least I got the dates to work. The only error I see in the console has to do with the glyphcon failing to load, even though it does. That's a separate issue I'm going to have to address eventually. I did see the autoclose setting in the docs after I posted but even setting it correctly it doesn't seem to work. I'm going to continue researching more today and I'll post an update in my original question with what I got to work so far.